# Selenium test project C# not running Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I request selenium test in running chrome but I encountering an `Exception`.
help me pleass. my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; 

namespace Acceptance_Test.Trader
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class AcceptenceTestBtcTraderCom
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        private StringBuilder _verificationErrors;
        private string _baseUrl;


        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(); // ** exception location is this one.
```

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current
>   directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The
>   driver can be downloaded at
>   chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: Can you show a few more lines of code after the last one? Also, can you give exception details?

Comment: _baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

            _verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

Comment: _driver = new ChromeDriver(); this is problem

Comment: Well where's the ChromeDriver stored? Have you downloaded it?!

Comment: yes i downloaded it but i cant run. I open the program and comes an article like this. Starting ChromeDriver <v2.10.267521> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed.

Comment: You don't have to run it. Just add its path in the code, as shown in my answer below and run it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add the path to the chrome driver:

```
_driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Folder_with_Chrome_driver");
```

If you have not downloaded the driver, you can find it [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).